# Class saving content of a file in dynamically allocated char array

Tags: c++, arrays

Part of a task for a homework is to load two text-files and save their content in a class using dynamically allocated char-arrays.
This is my class. What can I improve about it?

**Content.hpp**

```
class Content
{
public:
   Content(char* pContent);
   ~Content();
   char* getContent();
private:
   char* data;
};
```

**Content.cpp**

```
#include <cstring>
#include "Content.h"

using namespace std;

Content::Content(char* pContent){
   data = new char[sizeof pContent];
   strcpy(data, pContent);
}

Content::~Content(){
   delete[] data;
}

char* Content::getContent(){
   return data;
}
```

Comment: You sure this is going to work as you expect? In `Content.cpp`, this will definitely not work - `data = new char[sizeof pContent]`. `pContent` is a pointer so `sizeof(pContent)` is going to give you back `sizeof(char *)`.

Comment: "What can I improve?" would be a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup @Oli, I didn't know that one until now.

Comment: Once you fix that part (using Richard's idea), then your code would work. As an academic exercise, I guess this is what would be expected, though in production-level code, I'd recommend not doing manual memory management and instead using existing constructs like `std::string` (or `std::vector`, I don't know what the other expectations for your code are).

Comment: @birryree: Thank you. I'm also not a big fan of manual memory management but it was part of a homework regarding pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `sizeof pContent` with `strlen(pContent) + 1`, if you are storing strings (which it appears you are). This is because character arrays will **decay to pointers** in C & C++, which hold no length.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the first post and compiled with that change. It works flawlessly.

Comment: @Hedge here on stackoverflow, it isn't usual practice to edit your post with code changes suggested as an answer, as it removes context for the answer. As a result, I have rolled back your question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider declaring `const char* getContent()` instead of `char* getContent()` because it returns a private data member that you may want to prevent from being modified externally.